# Best way to write logic for pascal triangle shape in ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, nested-loops

I want output like this

```
    1
   0 1 
  0 1 0
 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: calculate how big the final line will be, then use that to calculate how much indenting the earlier lines need.

Comment: Thats called Triforce, Luke. Not all of us can do that

Comment: I 'm a beginner Marc I tried but i didn't get...

Answer (score 0):

Just add   `print " "*(5-i)` , Like this:

```
for i in 1..5
  print " "*(5-i)
  for j in 1..i
  if (i%2 == 0);
    k = (j%2 == 0) ? 1:0;
  else;
     k = (j%2 ==0) ? 0:1; 
  end
  print k," "
 end
 puts
end
```

Comment: Your wellcome! Check the answer if it serve you

Answer (score 0):

The n-th line is going to have n digits plus n-1 spaces - in case of the fifth line nine chars.
Generate each line as a string and print it using `puts str.center(9)`